# Is there a program like dropbox/mesh that allows you to sync a directory but filter on filetypes?

Tags: sync

I'm interested in syncing my zune folder among computers. I don't want to sync all the subscription music (wma files). I only want to synchronize mp3 files in the zune directory tree. Is there a tool that does that. Everything i've seen so far takes an all or nothing approach.

Edit: I'm trying if at all possible to find a free tool. In addition, i see two features that will enable my scenario. The ability to filter on file type, or the ability to exclude subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Syncplicity](http://www.syncplicity.com) and it works seamlessly.

Comment: Syncplicity does allow you to exclude directories which is nice. However I have to pay to sync over 2gb, and there's no option to only sync between computers and not save in the cloud. So, almost, but not quite. Thanks though!